# Rails, cancan - making an empty where query false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

I'm using cancan, and have the following in ability.rb -

```
can :contribute, Book do |book|
  book.contributions.where(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Ruby evaluates this as true whether or not the where query returns any match. How do I get the query to appropriately evaluate as false? Is this even the right approach in cancan?

Comment: try `book.contributions.where(user_id: user.id).any?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `any?` method on the records returned

`book.contributions.where(user_id: user.id)` will return [](empty array) if no records are found

`book.contributions.where(user_id: user.id).any?` will return `true` if any records are there and `false` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Use: `book.contributions.where(user_id: user.id).exists?`